How can i add a negative number to the displayArray?
I am trying to create a calculator and unable to calculate negative numbers because my current logic splits displayValue which is a string using regular expressions(Regex) to separate numbers and operators into an array displayArray.
so, when i try to assign a negative number (lets say for example -5 - 10) i want my displayArray to take it as ['-5', '-', '10'] but instead i get ['', '-', '5', '-', '10'].
so, my problem here is I know why its happening but I couldn't figure out how to get the first array instead of the later one?
expected: ['-5', '-', '10'].
Instead I get: ['', '-', '5', '-', '10'].
Here is my full code:
// Initialize variables
let displayValue = '';
let displayArray = [];

const screenDiv = document.getElementById('screen');
const numberButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.number');
const operatorButtons = document.querySelectorAll('.operator');

// Event listeners for number buttons
numberButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        displayValue += button.textContent;
        displayArray = displayValue.split(/([+\-*/])/);
        const [firstNumber, operator, secondNumber] = displayArray;

        if (displayArray.length === 3) {
            screenDiv.textContent = secondNumber;
        } else {
            screenDiv.textContent = firstNumber;
        }

        if (firstNumber === '0') {
            displayValue = '';
        }
    });
});

// Event listeners for operator buttons
operatorButtons.forEach(button => {
    button.addEventListener('click', () => {
        if (displayArray.length === 3) {
            displayValue = operate(); // Assuming operate() is a function to perform the operation
            screenDiv.textContent = displayValue;
            displayValue += button.textContent;
        } else {
            displayValue += button.textContent;
        }
    });
});


it's not possible to really help with what you've posted. fix up your question or consider keeping the display value and the stored values for doing the calculation on in seperate variables.

include your html, and a sample input / expected output

How do you add a negative number on a real calculator?

What is your question? What is the error you getting? Please provide more details.

@danielRICADO please check if my question is clear enough now, sorry about the confusion.

@RodrigoRodrigues please check if my question is clear enough now, sorry about the confusion.

@RickyMo please check if my question is clear enough now, sorry about the confusion.

In my experience, I suggest that you use the regular expression to separate the real no. from an expression.

It seems you are trying to use the same button for "negative operation" and "turn a number negative". That will not work, all calculators have separate buttons for that.

I suggest studying "Expression tree" and look for "how to convert infix expression to expression tree" to learn more about how a calculator work.

Based on your clarification, It seems that the issue with your string splitting is that you have to consider two cases for the - character:

at the beginning of the expression, you want it to be a negative signal;
in between numbers, you want it to be a subtraction operator.

You can address that directly by using a String.match instead of String.split, like this:
displayArray = displayValue.match(/((^-)?\d+)|([^\d]+)/g);


Even though the above will give you what you asked for, I don't think your approach will continue working for you much longer. You should consider having separate buttons for subtraction - and for changing signal (+/-), like most of the calculators you see in real life. You could even use different symbols for them, like a long dash for subtraction — and a short one for negative -.
Also, you cannot handle decimal numbers yet. You'd have to account for a possible dot in between digits.

Besides all that, if you plan to fully implement a calculator for learning purposes, I suggest you to learn about expression trees.
I could add a sample implementation of that by updating your code. Let me know if you need so.
